# android editText max limit

Tags: android, input, filter, android-edittext

After I set the max character limit for an editText using InputFilter.LengthFilter, is there a way to make editText to react at onTextChanged after it reaches the maximum number of characters? if not, is there a simple way to set a max number of characters to an editText and still react at onTextChanged event?

Answer (score 12):

In XML itself for EditText give the following Attrib,

```
  android:maxLength="20"
```

Comment: my max length is variable... it depends on some variables, so I have to set it from code.

Comment: then try this  InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(variable);
editEntryView.setFilters(FilterArray);

Comment: this is what I've done, but after the maximum limit is reached, I can't canch the event when user wants to type

Answer (score 0):

I was going through the same problem and some research on SO got me this solution. Thanks to @njzk2 for the brilliant solution. Posting it here so others can get the answer.

`maxLength` attribute in the `EditText` is actually an `InputFilter`, which you can write yourself and supply from code.

You can look at the implementation of InputFilter.LengthFilter, which basically returns `null` if there is no overflow. (see [link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/text/InputFilter.java#InputFilter.LengthFilter.filter%28java.lang.CharSequence%2Cint%2Cint%2Candroid.text.Spanned%2Cint%2Cint%29))

WIth a little modification to that : create an extension to `InputFilter.LengthFilter` in which you call `super` and compare it to `null` to decide if you need to display an alert.

```
editText.setInputFilters(new InputFilter[] {
    new InputFilter.LengthFilter(max) {
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            CharSequence res = super.filter(source, start, end, dest, dstart, dend);
            if (res != null) { // Overflow
                   Toast.makeText(this,"OVERFLOW!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            return res;
        }
    }
});
```